# What wood to build a bath-tub tray?

Tags: wood, woodworking

I'm new to wood working and I want to build my wife a bathtub tray that can hold a laptop (for Hulu watching) and a glass.  It doesn't need to hold anything else really.  But I don't know what type of wood to use for this.  What wood would be good?!

Comment: Related recommendation: get full coverage rider on your homeowner's insurance for the laptop. :)

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest using a hardwood like "teak" as it is commonly used in environments where it is exposed to water such as on boats and for outdoor furniture.

Comment: You could probably also look up how to care for the wood on boats.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest a wood that dries and doesn't mold easily. Something like a bamboo or cedar should work well.  Also, don't bother polyurethane'ing it, because the coating will just start to peel off with the humidity in the tub.

Answer (score 3):

Teak, finished with tung oil, is beautiful and very humidity-resistant. It is, however, insanely hard to work with. Same for mahogany.

Another option would be any tight-grain, dimensionally stable hardwood, like cherry or birch, and finish with a marine-grade urethane spar varnish. This is a bit more work than normal wood finishing, but the results are beautiful and very humidity/water resistant. The varnish is available from boat supply stores, and the keyword to google the technique to apply it is "brightwork" - the art of finishing woodwork for marine applications.

Answer (score 1):

I built one out of a knotty laminated pine panel, which looks good, was quite cheap, and doesn't warp easily.  Coated it with wax, and water hasn't been a problem for it.